# Filter array of filepaths if value contains an id substring found in an array of blacklisted ids

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter, word-boundary, partial-matches

I want to delete any element in Array 2 if it contains any of the elements in Array 1. From my research I've found that array_filter may be the one to use, but I confused about how I'd do this. I'll then need to reset the array keys. Could anyone suggest a method?

For example, any element containing '123998' exactly would be removed from Array 2. '1239986' would not be removed.

Array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123709
    [1] => 123797
    [2] => 124089
    [3] => 124153
)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => ../fish/cod/123709-sdfgsdfgvsadfg.pdf
    [1] => ../fish/cod/123797-sdfgsdfg-sdfg-sdfgs-dfg-sd.pdf
    [2] => ../fish/cod/123998-sdfgsdf-gsdf-gsd-fg-sdfg-.pdf
    [3] => ../fish/cod/123998-sdfgsdfg-sdf-gsdfg-sdf-g.pdf
    [4] => ../fish/cod/123998-sdfg.pdf
    [5] => ../fish/cod/123998-sdfgsdfgsfdg-sdfg.pdf
    [6] => ../fish/cod/124089-sdfgsdfg-sdfg-sdfg-.pdf
    [7] => ../fish/cod/124153-sdfgsdfgsdf-gsdfg.pdf
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `array_filter` sounds good, here is a way to use it :

```
$pruned_array = array_filter($array2, function($val2) use ($array1) {
  foreach($array1 as $val1) {
    if (strpos($val2, val1) !== false) 
      return $val2;
  }
});
```

If the position of the value to check is always the same (or if it follows the same pattern), it might be more efficient to check this part only instead of using `strpos`.

Comment: I assume that @Metzed would like to remove items exact by number, but this solution will accept value `../fish/cod/12399800-sdfgsdfg-sdf-gsdfg-sdf-g.pdf` ( two zeros added to the number ) that may be wrong.

Comment: @Nicolai Yes, maybe, the requirement "containing '123998'" is quite unclear. Not that hard to adapt though I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated the question. Any element containing '123998' exactly needs to be removed from Array 2. '1239986' would not be removed.

Comment: @Metzed Alright, and does it follow any strict and unique pattern at least ? It's always "/xxxxxx-" ? If so, what about `strpos($val2, '/' . $val1 . '-')`

Comment: Thank you @ClémentMalet - very good - thank you! I added `$pruned_array = array_values($pruned_array);` afterwards so as to reset the keys 0,1,2,3 - if that's the right way to do it...?

Comment: @Metzed Yes, probably the best way

Comment: @ClémentMalet Please edit your answer to implement the correct solution that you commented under the answer.  By the way, `array_filter()` expects boolean `return` values in its body.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
$array1=[...];
$array2=[...];
//go through each element
foreach($array2 AS $key=>$value)
{
    //check if element contains substring from first array
    foreach($array1 AS $v2)
    {
        if(strpos($value,$v2)!==FALSE)
        {
            //remove element
            unset($array2[$key]);
            //no need to check any further, if element is removed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not make whole `id` matches.  This unexplained answer risks "over-matching" by matching ids which are found within longer id substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Let say u defined first array as `$arr1` and second array as `$arr2`

```
foreach($arr2 as $key => $value)
{
   foreach($arr1 as $subkey => $subvalue)
   {
      if(strpos($subvalue, $value))
        unset($arr2[$key]);
   }
}
print_r($arr2);
```

Comment: This does not make whole `id` matches.  This unexplained answer risks "over-matching" by matching ids which are found within longer id substrings.

Answer (score 0):

We might not have enough information to fully understand the variability of your array of filepaths, so I'll be general in my advice.

Since your blacklist of substrings comes at the start of the filename and must be a complete-integer match, here is a way to strip down each filepath to its relevant component and compare it against a lookup array for a slight performance boost.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/drOK2))

```
$array = [
    '../fish/cod/123709-sdfgsdfgvsadfg.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/123797-sdfgsdfg-sdfg-sdfgs-dfg-sd.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/123998-sdfgsdf-gsdf-gsd-fg-sdfg-.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/123998-sdfgsdfg-sdf-gsdfg-sdf-g.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/123998-sdfg.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/123998-sdfgsdfgsfdg-sdfg.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/124089-sdfgsdfg-sdfg-sdfg-.pdf',
    '../fish/cod/124153-sdfgsdfgsdf-gsdfg.pdf',
];

$needles = [123709, 123797, 124089, 124153];
$lookup = array_flip($needles);

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($v) => !key_exists(strstr(basename($v), '-', true), $lookup),
    )
);
```

Alternatively, if the search substrings may occur in different positions in the "haystack" array, then the flexibility/utility of regex may be more appropriate.  I'll show word boundaries (`\b`) because it suits the sample input, but you could also use `/` at the start and `-` at the end of the pattern as "known" delimiting characters for your task.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XoVBN))

```
$regex = '~\b(?:' . implode('|', array_map(fn($v) => preg_quote($v, '~'), $needles)) . ')\b~';
var_export(preg_grep($regex, $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT));
```

Answer (score -1):

use below code for delete any element in Array 2 if it contains any of the elements in      Array 1 but before the you need to explode the array 2 for getting numric value for example "123709"

```
$array1 = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
$array2 = array('5', '6', '7', '1');
$temp = array();
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
   // Check the value hasn't already been found:
   if (!in_array($value, $array1))
   {
    //pushing the non duplicate value in temp array
    array_push($temp, $value);
   }
}
 //assign temp array to array2
 print_r($array2=$temp);
```

?>

Comment: This does not respect the requirements explained in the question.  This is an incorrect answer.